# leading for a Flex mx TextArea

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

When I set leading to 0 for a Flex mx TextArea I get strange results:
fontsize -> space between baselines
20 - 25 is 125% 25 - 31 is 124% shouldn't all of these be the same (should only be 100%)? Or least  follow a pattern, because I can't se any.
When i set leading to 0, the space between my baselines should be the same as the font size/height. This is not the case here.
How do I know how to get the space between the baseline to be equal to the height of the font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var ttLnHt:Number = _textArea.myUITextField.getLineMetrics(0).height;
    // guessPerc is variable for calculation = (100/(font size))*(total height of line);

```
var guessPerc:Number = (100/(textSize))*ttLnHt;
```